# Testing logs printed using other external library in golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-zap

My application uses other external library (which uses zap library) to print audit-logs and now I want to test the printed audit-logs in my golang testing file.
Can someone help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [zaptest](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap@v1.24.0/zaptest) package:

> Package zaptest provides a variety of helpers for testing log output.

As example, in your test:

```
func Test_zap(t *testing.T) {

    t.Run("Handle log message", func(t *testing.T) {
        // Given
        observedZapCore, observedLogs := observer.New(zap.InfoLevel)
        observedLogger := zap.New(observedZapCore)

        // When
        myFunction(observedLogger)

        // Then
        require.Equal(t, 1, observedLogs.Len())
        firstLog := observedLogs.All()[0]
        assert.Equal(t, "log myFunction", firstLog.Message)

    })
}
```

where myfunction is

```
func myFunction(logger *zap.Logger) {
    logger.Info("log myFunction")
}
```

Check also [this interesting article](https://medium.com/go-for-punks/handle-zap-log-messages-in-a-test-8503b25fe38f) about that

Comment: Yes I checked that too. But in my case the function which prints logs doesn't accept any arguments of type *zap.Logger. The function resides in external library.